# I need to conduct an interview with a sofer (scribe)

Tags: sefer-torah, safrus

I am a Bible teacher at a Christian school and I am wanting to research and possibly write more about the process of scribes creating a sefer Torah scroll. I would really enjoy and be honored to conduct a Zoom or Skype interview with someone who is a professional sofer (scribe). I know little about the process but would like to learn and be able to better appreciate the work of a scribe so that I can 1) teach it to my students and 2) begin the process of writing a small book on the complexities of being a scribe.. Can anyone help me locate and conduct an interview with a real sofer? It does not matter where they live.

Comment: I don’t know of any but I can recommend a book called INSIDE STAM which will hopefully address your questions.

Comment: Hi @Gabrielrutledge and welcome to Mi Yodeya. You might want to consider the Torah Live - they have a number of series one of which centres around the sefer Torah including an episode on the making and writing of a Torah. It also has available teaching resources - https://torahlive.com/courses/sefer-torah/

Comment: Pre-pandemic, the Bible Museum in DC had a resident sofer for exactly this reason.